# Localstorage giving unexpected results after using getItem() and setItem()

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to make a simple to do list for groceries where I would add, delete or update items in that list. I am also storing these values as an `array of objects` with the key of `list`.

I have a function called `addToLocalStorage()` which does all of this by accessing the initial `list` of items and then adds a new item to the list.

However, once I `console.log()` the previous list of items after adding a single item, it shows both the items (The one which I am adding after the `console.log()` statement).

Here is the function:

```
function addToLocalStorage(id, value)
{
    const groc = {id, value};
    let items = localStorage.getItem('list')?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list')):[];
    console.log("Previous items", items);
    items.push(groc);
    console.log("Pushing ", groc);
    localStorage.setItem('list',JSON.stringify(items));
    console.log("Right Now the list is ", items);
}
```

The id here is randomly generated (taking the current milliseconds).

When I add the first item `eggs`, the output is correct as expected and the `console.log()` statement displays an empty list of `Previous Items`.

```
Adding to the list
Previous items []
Pushing  {id: '1685891620219', value: 'Eggs'}
Right Now the list is  [{…}]
0: {id: '1685891620219', value: 'Eggs'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

When the second item `Milk` is added, the `Previous Items` shows the list containing the second item being added. As per my understanding, it should only return the first item.

```
Adding to the list
Previous items [{…}] [{…}]
0: {id: '1685891620219', value: 'Eggs'}
1: {id: '1685891909713', value: 'Milk'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
Pushing  {id: '1685891909713', value: 'Milk'}
Right Now the list is (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: '1685891620219', value: 'Eggs'}
1: {id: '1685891909713', value: 'Milk'}
length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Please correct me if I am wrong and explain how this behavior is possible.

Comment: The `console` API is asynchronous and so you can be fooled by those effects.

Comment: As pointed by @Pointy, `console` API is asynchronous. Try logging the items before you do `JSON.parse`

Comment: Or you could `console.log(items.map(i => i.id))` or something like that. The basic problem is that items may not be logged until after it has been changed, but if you make a new value to log then you'll get something less surprising.

Comment: Thankyou guys! I thought this was an error and it was driving me crazy.